# UIView goes under top status bar, it came back to right position when scrolling collection view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, safearealayoutguide

I am facing an issue with UIView which goes under top bar. But it placed at right position when I scroll collection view which is below white view showing in Image.

[image: white view goes under status bar]

After scroll collection view :

[image: after scroll collectionview]

can anyone have idea why this happened?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you pin collection view using safe area layout guides? Would be useful to see what constraints you've set up.

Comment: yes.. I took stack view. inside that I put that white view and collection view.

Comment: so for white view and collection view, I have not given any constraint. Because its in stack view.

Comment: And how did you configure stack view?

Comment: could you try to set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false in viewController,and check the result.